Launch kubernetes-dashboard in a logged-in state by pressing button in web app
I have a web app that provides links to all system's dashboards for user's convenience.
It has a button for kubernetes-dashboard too.
When a user clicks on a button, i would like to open a new page with Kubernetes dashboard and i would like to automatically authenticate user. ServiceAccount token would be generated every time.
When I test this with Requestly it works. When I add generated token to haproxy it works. But I want the token to be dynamic.
I tried using the following format https://k8s-dashboard/dashboard/?token=
dashboard didn't like it. haproxy had issues extracting the token with urlp(token). couldn't get it to work.
I tried to pass request header in my app's backend but that didn't work either.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I figured it out, Have to set a cookie before opening a new window.
http.post(url, data, config)
                    .then(function (success) {
                        var user_token = success.data.status.token;
                        document.cookie = `token=${user_token}; path=/dashboard; secure`;
                        window.open(`${$dashboard_url}/dashboard/`);
                    }, function (error) {
                        alerts.danger(JSON.stringify(error));
                    })
                    .catch(function (ex) {
                        alerts.danger("Error:" + ex.stack);
                    });

